# peer.on('calll') is never being called

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webrtc, peerjs

## Peer js is not working

I am just creating peerjs video streaming application in NodeJs and ReactJs

---

The below code is working fine, i am able to create new peer and `open` event is also working.

```js
const peer = new Peer(undefined,{
            host:"/",
            port:"5001"
        });

peer.on('open',id=>{
  socket.emit('join-room', roomId,id);
})
```

---

On server side whenever `'join-room'` event is emitted, server will emit another event `'user-disconnected'` and passes `userId (peerjs)` to client.

```js
// server.js
socket.on('join-room',(roomId,userId)=>{
    console.log(`user ${userId} joined ${roomId}`);
    socket.join(roomId);
    socket.to(roomId).emit('user-connected',userId);

    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        socket.to(roomId).emit('user-disconnected', userId)
    })
})
```

---

Whenever  `'user-connected'` is triggered on client side I'm calling `connectToNewUser` and up to this is working fine.

```js
socket.on('user-connected',userId=>{
    console.log("New user connected...")
    connectToNewUser(userId, stream)
});
```

---

## Error

This is being logged on console `console.log('connectToNewUser',1222.....)` there is no error.

But, this `call.on('stream')` is never being called

```js
connectToNewUser(userId, stream) {
    console.log('connectToNewUser',userId)
    const call = peer.call(userId, stream);
    const video = getVideo();
    call.on('stream', userVideoStream => {
      // never called
      console.log('connectToNewUser','on','stream')
      addVideoStream(video, userVideoStream)
    });
    call.on('close', () => {
      video.remove()
    })

    peers[userId] = call
}
```

The reason of `call.on('stream')` is never being called is `peer.on('call')` is never being called.

```js
peer.on('call', call => {
    // never called
    console.log('This peer is being called...');
    call.answer(stream)
    const video = getVideo();
    call.on('stream', userVideoStream => {
        console.log('This peer is being called...on-stream...');
        addVideoStream(video, userVideoStream)
    })
});
```

[Github repo](https://github.com/ats1999/conference)

Comment: DId you end up getting this to work? I'm having the exact same problem, my local video works fine but peer.on('call') is never triggered. I've tried all the solutions below and none worked.

Comment: Nope, i didn’t tried after that. We used plain Javascript after that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only problem with your code is that you are emitting user-connected event from server before initializing peer.on("call") event on client which eventually leads this event to be missed by new client.
The best solution for this is to emit a ready event after initializing peer.on("call",...) event.

```
peer.on('call', call => {
console.log('This peer is being called...');
call.answer(stream)
const video = getVideo();
call.on('stream', userVideoStream => {
    console.log('This peer is being called...on-stream...');
    addVideoStream(video, userVideoStream)
})})
socket.emit("ready")`
```

And then on server side call the "user-connected" broadcast event inside the listener for "ready" event:

```
socket.on('join-room',(roomId,userId)=>{
console.log(`user ${userId} joined ${roomId}`);
socket.join(roomId);
socket.on('ready',()=>{
socket.broadcast.to(roomId).emit('user-connected',userId);
})

socket.on('disconnect', () => {
 socket.to(roomId).emit('user-disconnected', userId)
})})
```

This will broadcast user-connected event after the client is ready to recieve peer.on("call". ..
.) event

Answer (score 3):

I also had the same problem, after going through more than 10+ solutions on StackOverflow, here is the thing I suggest.

connectToNewUser() gets triggered before the user has finished the navigator promise.

Try to modify to this:

```js
socket.on('user-connected',userId=>{
    console.log("New user connected...")
    //connectToNewUser(userId, stream)
    setTimeout(connectToNewUser,1000,userId,stream)
});
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I think your code is something like this

```
const peer = new Peer(undefined,{host:"/",port:"5001"})
peer.on('open',id=>{
  socket.emit('join-room', roomId,id)
})

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    video : true,
    audio : true
}).then( stream => {

    socket.on('user-connected',userId=>{
         // call the new user and send our stream
    });
    
   peer.on('call',call=>{
        // pick up the call and send our stream
   })

})
```

whenever a new client joins a new peer Object is created after which the socket emits `join-room` and the server broadcasts the `user-connected` to all the other clients

so now when the new user joins the `user-connected` function of all the other client is called in which all the other clients call the new client .

one key thing to note is that the  `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(video : true,audio : true})` takes some time

So when a new client joins all the other clients instantly call the new client but the function to pick up the call i.e. `peer.on('call',call=>{})` may not be defined yet on the new client so that's  why the new clients does not response because it is still setting up its video stream

to fix this you must join the room after setting up the video stream
so something like this

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    video : true,
    audio : true
}).then( stream => {

    const peer = new Peer(undefined,{host:"/",port:"5001"})
    peer.on('open',id=>{
        socket.emit('join-room', roomId,id)
    })

    socket.on('user-connected',userId=>{
         // call the new user and send our stream
    });
   
   peer.on('call',call=>{
        // pick up the call and send our stream
   })

})
```

Answer (score 2):

Here the Peer object is getting created before Camera and/or Mic are ready to use.

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
  video: true,
  audio: true
}).then(stream => { 
    //peer.on('call')
})
```

`peer.on('call')` will be implemented by browser only once `getUserMedia()` will finish execution.

Thing is that you are receiving a call event but there is no handler is ready to handle that event yet. Best solution would be to join the room once the media is ready to use.

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
  video: true,
  audio: true
}).then(stream => {   
  const myPeer = new Peer(undefined, {
    host: '/',
    port: '3001'
  })
  myPeer.on('open', id => { 
    socket.emit('join-room', ROOM_ID, id)
  })

  myPeer.on('call', call => { })
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is similar to a project that I'm working on. I had trouble with where I was initiating the `peer` instance. I had to move it up one level in my component tree, because something I was doing was causing a re-render and the `peer` instance was being re-created, with a new `id`.

Also check where you're creating your socket. Make sure that your `user-connected` event is being registered in a `useEffect()`.

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    videoSocket = initiateVideoSocket(roomId, username, peer.id);
    // When a viewer connects, this event is emitted and the streamer will connect to the viewer.
    videoSocket.on("user-connected", (roomId, viewerPeerId) => {
      connectToNewViewer(viewerPeerId, videoStream);
    });
  }, [videoStream]);
```

```js
  const viewerVideoSocket = initiateVideoSocket(
    room,
    props.username,
    viewerPeerId
  );

  const viewerChatSocket = initiateChatSocket(room, props.username);
  let streamerVideoDiv;

  useEffect(() => {
    viewerVideoSocket.emit(
      "user-connected",
      room,
      props.username,
      viewerPeerId
    );

    viewerPeer.on("call", (call) => {
      call.answer();
      call.on("stream", (stream) => {
        streamerVideoDiv = document.getElementById("streamer-video");
        const content = document.createElement("video");
        content.srcObject = stream;
        content.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", () => {
          content.play();
        });
        streamerVideoDiv.append(content);
      });
    });

    return () => {
      disconnectSocket();
    };
  }, []);
```

Comment: `peer.on('open',id=>{
  socket.emit('join-room', roomId,id);
})` this is working fine, that means peer is able to  make a connection with the sever

Comment: Right. So your socket is emitting the `join-room` event and the function is being called. Are you able to `console.log()` your `peer` instance to see if that is working correctly?

Comment: yes, socket is emitting `join-room` event

Comment: Also, in `connectToNewUser()` function, this is logged `console.log('connectToNewUser',userId)` successfully, but I think this statement is not working `const call = peer.call(userId, stream)`

Comment: If you have time, can you go through the repo https://github.com/ats1999/conference

Comment: i have spent a lot of time, but still I'm not able to resolve this.

Comment: I pulled your code, and I'll be able to look at it more in depth later. But from a quick look two things. First, when I create a room and then click "Join Room", I'm directed to the room page, but none of the data is available when the component loads. There is no reference of the `VideoApp` instance created until after I refresh the page. Second, there is no Peer ID being set when you instantiate a `VideoApp` instance. I don't know if it's because you're passing in `undefined` when you create it. I'll be able to look more later if you haven't figured it out by then.

Comment: `until after I refresh the page`, it's true before I fix this I would like to fix the connection of `peerjs`

Comment: `it's because you're passing in undefined` the reason why I'm passing undefined is I would like to generate a unique user id by the `peerjs` server.

Comment: `peerjs server->>`  i installed the `peerjs` globally then run the server

Comment: `install-> npm i -g peerjs`

Comment: `run -> peerjs --port 5001`

Comment: If you want the PeerJS server to generate the ID's, then you don't pass in undefined. You can just create the peer object like `let my_peer = new Peer()`. If you need to run it on your own server, you need to generate your own ID's for each peer connection.

https://github.com/peers/peerjs-server

Answer (score 0):

You must declare peer in the stream call back function as below:

```js
myVideo.muted = true;
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia ({
    video: true,
    audio: true
}).then(
    stream => {
        const myPeer = new Peer (undefined, {


            host: '/',
            port: '4001'
        });
        
        myPeer.on('open', id => {
            
            socket.emit('join-room', ROOM_ID, id)
            console.log("!@1")
            
        })

        addVideoStream(myVideo,stream)
        
        socket.on('user-connected', userId => {
            console.log("user is connected with id: ", userId);
            // connectToNewUser(userId, stream)
            const call = myPeer.call(userId, stream);
            console.log('call');
            const video = document.createElement('video');
            call.on('stream', userVideoStream => {
                addVideoStream(video, userVideoStream);
            })
            call.on('close', () => {
                video.remove()
            })
        })
        myPeer.on('call', call => {
            call.answer(stream)
            console.log("CALL"); 
        })

        
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple...

Set debug level to 3 when initializing the peer and then you will see the error

peer.call is not running since you may not be passing the parameters , id or stream...